# Drupal 6 template redirect

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-6

There are a few solutions to redirect if user is not logged in. What if I do not wish to redirect to login page but to main domain webpage

So here this is easy, drupal goto brings us to domain/user/login, but i want redirect to go to domain. Of course, drupal_goto(''); causes an error!

```
 global $user;
   if ($user->uid == 0 && arg(0) != 'user' && arg(1) != 'login'){
   drupal_goto('user/login');
 }
```

(this is placed in theme template.php file under function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) )

Comment: `<front>` is the token for the front page so `drupal_goto('<front>');` should work

Comment: I tried. Nope, "resulted in too many redirects" ... page doesn't load. I'm going to try using drupal_is_front_page() approach. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why do all main page redirects caust this problem??

Comment: node wouldn't work either, bypass using a different page as home page. created with a page module like /home or /main_page

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way is to add the destination parameter to the log out link.

So if your link looks like `example.com/logout` change it to `example.com/logout&destination=node/1`. After you logout, Drupal will automatically redirect you to the destination. Generating the links is very easy as well, something like this:

```
  <?php if ($user->uid) : ?>
    <?php print l(t('log out'), 'logout', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())); ?>
    <?php print l($user->name, 'user'); ?>
  <?php else : ?>
    <?php print l(t('log in'), 'user', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

**Update 12.03.2013**: For more advanced options regarding the redirects you can install this module: [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

Comment: So if a random person tries to access domain/member, he should be rerouted to the main page?

Comment: Don't mention it. I don't understand the question about rerouting someone to the front page if he tries to access a page. Coming back to the problem of: "where to redirect the user after he logs out?", you have to options: to the front page or to the last page that he was on (preferably). If I'm visiting example.com/node/6 as a logged in user and I click log-out I expect to see the same page again. Not the log in page or the front-page. But using the parameter destination is the easiest way to control the redirect.

Comment: what if the user is not logged in but tries to access a protected page?

Comment: what does this has to do with the redirect after logout? The user should see a "access denied" page.

Comment: i was hoping to instead re-direct to mainpage rather than see an access denied page

Comment: also my original question wasn't about redirect after logout. it was about redirect in general

Comment: Well a too general question is not likely to get an answer for all the possible situations that you want: logout, access denied etc. There should be a module out there to satisfy your needs. I've updated my answer with such a module.

Comment: it is not general at all! This is a simple problem of redirect through a theme template edit which covers all pages!

Comment: I'm confused now, you stated: _it was about redirect in general_. I'm afraid I don't understand what you need so I can't give more details. I've already mentioned a way to redirect after login and another module who takes care of other situations. Is there any situation left uncovered?